# Why is it only outputting Mage?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

It only is giving "Mage" even if "Warrior" was selected. I can't seem to know why. Does anyone have ideas?

```
    void OnGUI(){
    isMageClass = GUILayout.Toggle(isMageClass, "Mage Class");
    isWarriorClass = GUILayout.Toggle(isWarriorClass, "Warrior Class");
    if(GUILayout.Button("Create")){
        if(isMageClass)
        {
            newPlayer.PlayerClass = new BaseMageClass();
        }else if (isWarriorClass)
        {
            newPlayer.PlayerClass = new BaseWarriorClass();
        }
        newPlayer.PlayerLevel = 1;
        newPlayer.Stamina = newPlayer.PlayerClass.Stamina;
        newPlayer.Endurance = newPlayer.PlayerClass.Endurance;
        newPlayer.Intellect = newPlayer.PlayerClass.Intellect;
        newPlayer.Strength = newPlayer.PlayerClass.Strength;

        Debug.Log("player Class: " + newPlayer.PlayerClass.CharacterClassName);
        Debug.Log("player level: " + newPlayer.PlayerLevel);
        Debug.Log("player Stamina: " + newPlayer.Stamina);
        Debug.Log("player Endurance: " + newPlayer.Endurance);
        Debug.Log("player Intellect: " + newPlayer.Intellect);
        Debug.Log("player Strength: " + newPlayer.Strength);
    }
}
```

Comment: Can both toggle booleans be true at the same time? Does the `BaseWarriorClass` incorrectly identify itself as Mage?

Comment: How could that be fixed?

Comment: For the toggle booleans, just ensure that when one is set to true, that the other is set to false. If the method in the question is the only time they are changed, then they just need to start off as opposite values. As for `BaseWarriorClass` identifying itself incorrectly, check how it sets members, (I'm mostly referring to `BaseWarriorClass`'s `CharacterClassName` being "Mage", assuming it's one of the debug strings showing "Mage" no matter what). Though I definitely agree with DaveEP, in that stepping through the method with a debugger would help

Answer (score 0):

Since 'isMageClass' is defined then it will take the

```
    if(isMageClass)
    {
        newPlayer.PlayerClass = new BaseMageClass();
    }
```

every time and never even look at the

```
    else if (isWarriorClass)
    {
        newPlayer.PlayerClass = new BaseWarriorClass();
    }
```

I'm surprised you didn't spot that when stepping through with the debugger (tell me you stepped through with the debugger.... please!)

Comment: if `isMageClass` is `false`, it will look at the `else if`

Comment: Then it should work - and I would still be stepping through with a debugger which should answer everything

Comment: How would you set it to false?

Comment: Have you stepped through this with a debugger?   When you get there what is the value of isMageClass ?   Is it ever anything but true?

Comment: I just run it through a debugger. I do not know how to fix it still.

Comment: I don't know what you mean by 'it just runs through'.   Did you put a break point on the if(isMageClass) so it stops there and you can see what the values are?

Comment: How are you trying to view the value?   Everything has a value or is null.

Comment: Where do you look to find the value/null, I don't see where it says it.

Comment: It doesn't just appear, you have to hover the mouse over the variable and it will generally show in a popup.  If not, you can right click and add a 'watch' on a variable.

Comment: It says "(field) bool CreateCharacter.isMageClass"

Comment: This is fairly simple stuff but hard to describe in a couple of lines of test.  I would suggest you spend some time on YouTube or other sites learning how to use the debugger and looking at variables. You'll thank yourself everyday for this small amount of time invested because this knowledge will help with every program you ever write in VS..